# Xcode 10 - Interface Builder could not open the document Main.storyboard" because it does not exist

Tags: xcode, import, storyboard, program-entry-point, builder

I just imported an old project I did in May 2018 with an older version of Xcode and cannot seem to fix this issue. Attached is a screenshot of the issue I get. I searched everywhere and tried a lot of things but nothing seem to work. p.s. I just upgraded the Swift to 4.2.

[image]

Comment: In you list of project files, either you see the file in white (present), red (can't find path) or you don't see it (not in the project). Eventually, close+reopen Xcode and clean DerivedData.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this out.

After returning to some work that was stored in a cloud, I got the same Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard errors.

For some reason, when importing a file/folder from a cloud, a .xml suffix is added to Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard files.

[The following image shows the files stored on Google Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Doy.png)

[And then after download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRJyK.png)

Just delete the .xml suffix and clean.

Comment: same issue. Thanks wil :)